# Can't automount smartphone in LXDE anymore

Tags: automounting, lxde, void-linux, smartphone

I used to plug in my smartphone into my laptop to access the internal storage as well as SD-card storage. Since some recent updates it stopped working. I unfortuntaly cannot narrow it down to a specific date or update, because I didn't mount it for some time.

Mounting the smartphone was a two-step process in LXDE, because after plugging the phone, I had to change the phone's behavior (lineageOS) from pure charge mode into file transfer mode. After plugging the USB cord the drives appeared along with the message whether I wanted to mount it. After switching the phone to file transfer mode, the directories and files started to appear inside LXDE's filemanager.

Now, after plugging the phone, I directly get a message about .service file.
[image]
I can acknowledge that but the drive's folder stays empty even after I prompt the phone to switch to data transfer.

I can exclude the possibility that some updates on the phone might have triggered that, because I ommitted some oft those for a while (different story).

The error message is:

```
The name :<n.m> was not provided by any .service files
```

n.m is different after reboot.

I figured out, that this message is somehow d-bus related, but nothing further. I do not know how to debug this behavior or where the real error messages from d-bus might be stored.

What logfile do I have to search for? Why could updating of e.g.

- dbus
- lxde

or anything have affected the correct mounting process for my phone?

Comment: `Since some recent updates it stopped working`  ... updates to what? ... phone or laptop?

Comment: only laptop. I wrote, that I had omitted the updates for lineageOS for a while.